# How to open links from a txt file in python?

Tags: python, html, url, hyperlink

I have managed to create a txt file with a list of all the links I want to open and get information from, but I am unable to find a way to open these links in order to scan the html. Any help would be much appreciated! I am very much a beginner in python, so please write any answers as simply as possible as chances are I won't be able to understand it :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, we don't  write the code for you, but we can help you with any errors/difficulties you might encounter. Please edit your post and add the code you have written so far in order to retrieve the .txt file

Answer (score 0):

First you want to open the txt file using open().

```
fp = open('path/to/file.txt')
```

Then for each line in that txt file you can iterate over each line in a loop.

```
for line in fp.readlines():
    print line

#ensure to close the file after
fp.close()
```

Furthermore you can always append each line to a list to use later.

```
myList=[]
fp = open('path/to/file.txt')
for line in fp.readlines():
    myList.append(line)
fp.close()
```

Here is a way to open the links as well.

```
import webbrowser

for i in myList:
    webbrowser.open(myList[i])
```

Here are some tutorials on [readlines ()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm) and on [open() & close() files](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)